# Payment Method's name is not displaying in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, sales, transactional-mail, invoice-pdf

In checkout process when one of payment method is clicked the calculation and everything working fine but in the progress bar the **method name is absent**(ex. Pay on Delivery, Pay on Card).
[image]

It's absent in everywhere including adminhtml's sales section under **Payment Information** block the output is

> Order was placed using BDT

After debugging what I've understood is

```
> {{var payment_html}}, getChildHtml('order_payment'), $this->getPaymentHtml()
```

these fields return empty value!! can anyone help?

Comment: Is it default Magento installation?

Comment: Do u have enabled payments in admin panel?

Comment: @sohel, I’m using a theme, it was okay before but now I dont know why its not working!

Comment: @konrad, payment methods are working fine just the name of these are not showing!!